# Stream audio from Android with HTML5/WebRTC - Red5

Tags: android, red5, webrtc

I'm building a prototype and am looking for a simple way to stream audio from Android to a server (probably Red5). Can this be done with WebRTC?  Is there another approach I should try first?

Answer (score 0):

If it's audio only, you can stick with sip, which is more mature and more widely supported. There's a lot of client either in JavaScript or Java.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to stream audio to Red5 from Android is by using Air. I created a mobile app that does this and you may find it on the play store: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.org.gregoire.mobile.AudioBroadcaster

FYI the app is FREE.